# How to find and solve for multiple solutions in Sudoku Solver?

Tags: java, recursion, sudoku

I have created a program to take in a txt file for a sudoku board. I save it into a 2D array and have a solve function in order to solve it. My only problem that I am left with is how would I add in the ability to find another solution once one is already found? Once a solution is found I would ask the user three options. If they would want to find another solution, change a value in the board, and exit.

Below would be the 2D array being the board and 0 indicated blank

```
int[][] grid = {{3, 0, 6, 5, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0},
                 {5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 {0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1},
                 {0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0},
                 {9, 0, 0, 8, 6, 3, 0, 0, 5},
                 {0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0},
                 {1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0},
                 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4},
                 {0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0}};
```

Below is the functions in order to solve the board. While this is enough to solve the board one time. It does not work to solve another time find another solution. Which is what I need for option A from the users input.

```
private static boolean isRowAvailable(int[][] board, int coordinateX, int value){
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            if(board[coordinateX][i] == value)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isColumnAvailable(int[][] board, int coordinateY, int value){
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            if(board[i][coordinateY] == value)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isSquareAvailable(int[][] board, int coordinateX, int coordinateY, int value){
        int firstNewX = 0, secondNewX = 0, firstNewY = 0, secondNewY = 0;

        if(coordinateX >= 0 && coordinateX <= 2){
            firstNewX = 0;
            secondNewX = 2;
        }
        else if(coordinateX >= 3 && coordinateX <= 5){
            firstNewX = 3;
            secondNewX = 5;
        }
        else if(coordinateX >= 6 && coordinateX <= 8){
            firstNewX = 6;
            secondNewX = 8;
        }

        if(coordinateY >= 0 && coordinateY <= 2){
            firstNewY = 0;
            secondNewY = 2;
        }
        else if(coordinateY >= 3 && coordinateY <= 5){
            firstNewY = 3;
            secondNewY = 5;
        }
        else if(coordinateY >= 6 && coordinateY <= 8){
            firstNewY = 6;
            secondNewY = 8;
        }

        for(int i = firstNewX; i <= secondNewX; i++){
            for(int j = firstNewY; j <= secondNewY; j++){
                if(board[i][j] == value)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }

    private static boolean isAvailable(int[][] board, int coordinateX, int coordinateY, int value){
        if(isRowAvailable(board, coordinateX, value) &&
                isColumnAvailable(board, coordinateY, value) &&
                isSquareAvailable(board, coordinateX, coordinateY, value) &&
                board[coordinateX][coordinateY] == 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean findEmptySpot(int[][] board, int[] coordinates){
        for(coordinates[0] = 0; coordinates[0] < 9; coordinates[0]++){
            for(coordinates[1] = 0; coordinates[1] < 9; coordinates[1]++){
                if(board[coordinates[0]][coordinates[1]] == 0)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean solveSudoku(int[][] board){
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        int[] coordinates = {x, y};

        if (!findEmptySpot(board, coordinates))
            return true;

        x = coordinates[0];
        y = coordinates[1];

        for(int num = 1; num <= 9; num++)
        {
            if (isAvailable(board, x, y, num))
            {
                board[x][y] = num;

                if(solveSudoku(board))
                    return true;

                board[x][y] = 0;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Below is the function to handle users input for the menu

```
switch(upperResponse){
                case 'A':
                    //instructions for finding another solution
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    changeConstraint();
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Please enter valid option");
            }
```

The expected result I am aiming for would be for this below

```
Solving the puzzle below:
0 0 1 6 0 0 0 7 0
0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 6
0 7 0 0 4 0 3 0 0
0 0 9 0 0 0 6 0 3
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 8 1 0 0 9 2
0 0 6 0 0 0 0 2 5
0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0
3 2 0 4 0 0 8 0 9 
A solution is:
5 3 1 6 8 2 9 7 4
8 9 4 1 3 7 2 5 6
6 7 2 5 4 9 3 8 1
1 8 9 7 2 5 6 4 3
2 5 3 9 6 4 7 1 8
4 6 7 8 1 3 5 9 2
7 1 6 3 9 8 4 2 5
9 4 8 2 5 6 1 3 7
3 2 5 4 7 1 8 6 9
What would you like to do? 
(A) find another solution, (B) change a constraint  (C) quit
Input: A
Another solution is:
5 3 1 6 8 2 9 7 4
8 9 4 1 3 7 2 5 6
6 7 2 5 4 9 3 8 1
1 8 9 7 2 5 6 4 3
2 5 3 9 6 4 7 1 8
4 6 7 8 1 3 5 9 2
7 4 6 3 9 8 1 2 5
9 1 8 2 5 6 4 3 7
3 2 5 4 7 1 8 6 9
```

Comment: To make your code [mcve] and make it easier to help, add your code for handling user's input and hard code the input data as a matrix.

Comment: I added everything I can that can help. Thank you! @c0der

Comment: Your question doesn’t seem to have anything to do with solving sudoku but rather about accessing and storing data ,like the original board and found solutions?

Comment: Yea it is just I can not figure out a way for option A which is to find another solution. Would I save a specific value from original board or save the first solution? That is what I would like to find out @JoakimDanielson

Comment: I would load the original board from file again so that a second solving of the puzzle would use the same logic/flow as the first and I would keep previous solutions in a list/array.

Comment: The thing is that every time it just solves with the same solution @JoakimDanielson

Comment: So now the problem _is_ about the sudoku solving? Stop posting comments and put some energy into updating your question so it is clear what your issue is and what you need helps with.

Comment: Yea sorry that is what I meant by finding a way to solve for another solution